# $ 1 - \cos 2 \Theta$ can be rewritten as $1 - \left( 1 - 2 \sin^2 \Theta\right)$ - I don't understand why though

Tags: polar-coordinates, trigonometry

Going through a video I saw this and wasn't sure how to sort it -

given the following :

$$  r = 4 \left( 1 - \cos 2 \Theta \right) $$

the part in parenthesis $ 1 - \cos 2 \Theta$ can be rewritten as $1 - \left( 1 -
2 \sin^2 \Theta\right)$.

I'm not sure where this comes from though? I have a sheet of identities, but this
isn't on there. If anyone could point me in the right direction as to why this
can be rewritten as such that'd be ace.

Looking through a sheet such as [this
one](http://media.wiley.com/Lux/91/323191.image0.png) I can't really intuit
them, I just use them when needed (I couldn't write a proof).

Cheers.

Comment: $\cos2\theta$ is the middle of the double-angle formulas in the bottom left of your formula sheet.

Comment: are you familiar with $\cos2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$ (or maybe another formula where $\cos2\theta$ is the LHS)?

Comment: @drhab no this is pretty new to me, and I'm self teaching (if that makes any difference). The thing I'm finding at the moment is that if I am given a formula such as these I can apply it, but I don't have an intuitive understanding of why they work or what they're doing. $y=x^2$ is quite understandable, but these don't really mean anything even though I can see that they work when the answer matches the books or whatnot... Sos if that's a bit off topic !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three forms of the $\cos{2x}$ "double-angle" formula, which you can shift between by using $\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}=1$:
$$ \cos{2x} = \cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x} = \cos^2{x}-(1-\cos^2{x}) = 2\cos^2{x}-1 \\
= (1-\sin^2{x})-\sin^2{x}, $$
so
$$ \begin{align}
\cos{2x} &= \cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x} \\
 &= 2\cos^2{x}-1 \\
&= 1-2\sin^2{x}.
\end{align} $$

Answer (score 1):

Use this identity $\sin^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$:

---

$$ 1 - \cos(2x)=1 - \left( 1 - 2 \sin^2(x)\right) \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$ 1 - \cos(2x)=1 - \left( 1 - 2 \left(\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))\right)\right) \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$ 1 - \cos(2x)=1 - \left( 1 - \left(1-\cos(2x)\right)\right) \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$ 1 - \cos(2x)=1 - \left( 1 -1+\cos(2x)\right) \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$ 1 - \cos(2x)=1 - \left( 0+\cos(2x)\right) \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$ 1 - \cos(2x)=1 - \cos(2x) $$